# Google Spreadsheet won't display the leading space in the cell

Tags: google-sheets, html

For following graph, the Google Spreadsheet won't display the leading space before `android:xxx`. How could I enable it or how could I add a leading space ?

```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="700">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.4"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.6"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="-45"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="400" />
   </set>
```

Comment: You're indeed working with a Google Spreadsheet, but the coding involved belongs either on [SO] or Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: @Jacob: Coding/programming questions are **off-topic** at [android.se].

Answer (score 1):

I've done some research and it is not possible. See following two threads:

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/zDLZhcxvqXw
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/AOdIi7Jqp3I